# Deploy elasticsearch with url and open port

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I use this yml file to deploy elasticsearch on kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:5.6.16
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 2Gi
          limits:
            memory: 4Gi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
        - containerPort: 9300
        env:
        - name: discovery.type
          value: single-node
        - name: cluster.name
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: node.name
          value: node-1
```

How I can set permanent internal url which can be used to access the elasticsearch pod from another pod.
I can make this successfully this request on port 9200:

```
 curl -X GET 10.233.75.8:9200
{
  "name" : "uzspw5E",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "IB59izzDRTypCaZ3Nhbcgw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.6.16",
    "build_hash" : "3a740d1",
    "build_date" : "2019-03-13T15:33:36.565Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

But port 9300 is not working:

```
curl -X GET 10.233.75.8:9300
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.233.75.8 port 9300: Connection refused
```

Do you know how I can open this port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access the Elasticsearch service from another pod, consider creating a Kubernetes Service object that targets your Elasticsearch Deployment. This will provide a stable endpoint (the Service’s ClusterIP) that other pods can use to access the Elasticsearch API on port 9200.

Here’s an example of how you might define such a Service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
spec:
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9200
      targetPort: 9200
```

With this Service in place, other pods should be able to access the Elasticsearch API via http://elasticsearch:9200.

Answer (score 0):

A command line alternative using kubectl NodePort

Find out the name of your elasticsearch pod.

kubectl get pod |grep elasticsearch

Use it in below command inplace of elasticsearch-master-0

```
 kubectl expose pod elasticsearch-master-0 --type=NodePort --name=my-es-endpoint
```

this should normally return ..

```
service/my-es-endpoint exposed
```

Then the next step is to find the port mapping:

```
 kubectl get service | grep NodePort  



my-es-endpoint NodePort       IP    <none>                                           
 9300:30804/TCP,9200:32421/TCP,9600:31422/TCP,9650:31576/TCP   21s
```

The port numbers adjacent to 9200: or 9300: are the ports that you can use to hit the ES endpoint